# Capturing name in source page using xpath in python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml.html

I have the following url source page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="QQQ" value="AAA" />
<input type="hidden" name="WWW" value="BBB" />
<input type="hidden" name="EEE" value="CCC" />
<input type="hidden" name="WANTED" value="DDD" />
```

I want to extract `WANTED` where the value is `DDD` from that.
What I tried is:

```
token=tree.xpath('//input[@type="hidden"]/input[@value="DDD"]/@name')
```

but it gives me `QQQ`

Comment: you want the name attribut of what ? the first input node? the last input node ? It's unclear how you find "WANTED"

Comment: I want `WANTED` where the value is `DDD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the xpath:

```
//input[@type='hidden'][@value='DDD']/@name
```

Comment: Thank you. imagine Value is number, like `1` not `DDD`. in this situation how can I try?

Comment: then you should replace `DDD` with `1`.

Comment: try removing the quotes for it to represent a number. something like `[@value=1]`

Comment: @MortezaLSC This is rather pointless, if you do not show the _actual_ input document. Please edit your question and show the document you are really working on. Oh, and also show a _complete_ Python script instead of a single line.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
token=tree.xpath('//input[@type="hidden" and @value="DDD"]/@name')
```

Comment: Thank you. imagine Value is number, like `1` not  `DDD`. in this situation how can I try?

Comment: replace the `DDD` with `1`